# Trigonometry graphs sinusoidal waves

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

i need help on this questions. I couldn't figure how to determine for both question A and B.

But i have the answers for them, i just don't understand how the amplitude is 3 and so on.

[image: trigonometry graph]

Comment: Waldo stole $c$ !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the amplitude, take half the difference of the maximum and minimum values.  In this case, the amplitude is

$$a = \frac{1 - (-5)}{2} = \frac{6}{2} = 3$$

If you subtract the amplitude from the maximum value, you will find the average value.  In this case, the average value of the function is $1 - 3 = -2$.  If there were no vertical shift, the average value of the function would be zero.  Therefore, the vertical shift is

$$d = 0 - (-2) = 2$$

Since the sine function assumes its average value at $0$, there is no phase shift.  Hence, $c = 0$.

Observe that the graph shows that $3/4$ of a period is $1/2$.  Hence, one period is

$$\frac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{3}{4}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Since $\sin t$ has period $2\pi$, you can find the frequency by setting $bt = 2\pi$, where $t$ is the period of the sinusoidal function.  Here $t = 2/3$.  Thus,

\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{3}b & = 2\pi\\
b & = 2\pi \cdot \frac{3}{2}\\
b & = 3\pi
\end{align*}

Substituting for $a$, $b$, and $d$ yields $x = 3\sin(3\pi t) - 2$.

We can check this by substituting $0$ and $0.5$ for $t$.  If $t = 0$, then

$$x = 3\sin(0) - 2 = -2$$

If $t = 0.5$, then

$$x = 3\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) - 2 = 3(-1) - 2 = -3 - 2 = -5$$

Both values agree with the graph.